# groovy.xml.XmlParser issues parsing unique, colon-separated attributes

Tags: xml, groovy

I wrote a groovy script merging parts with matching attributes into a new xml file. As an identifier I use a list of elements out of a CSV file. If a match is found via the groovy xml parser, I append the whole node element into an output xml file.

But the input and the output of the nodes differ.

```
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:int">3</value>
```

The output is:

```
<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:int">3</value>
```

xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xs are unique identifier and the syntax is correct xml. But after using the groovy.xml.XmlParser only the first attribute is left.
Is this a groovy.xml.XmlParser bug?

Here is my short example to test this behavior:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlParser

class CreateSelectedXML {
    static void xmlHandling(List<String> listCodes, String TEST_FILE_NAME) {
        def docdup = new StringBuilder()

        listCodes.each { code ->
                File input = new File(TEST_FILE_NAME)
                def doc = new XmlParser().parse(input)
                doc.findAll{it.@code == code[0].toString()}.each {
                    def temp
                    temp = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(it).toString()
                    docdup.append(temp)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xmlns:...` is not really an attribute - it's a namespace declaration.

and namespace `xs`  declared with `xmlns:xs` is not used in your xml. that's why after serialization it's not there.

good explanation of namespaces in xml: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

however you could tell to XmlParser to ignore namespaces - then `xmlns:xs` will be handled as usual xml attribute and will be serialized after parsing.

```
def parser = new XmlParser(false,false)
```

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/XmlParser.html#%3Cinit%3E(boolean,boolean)

---

note: `xs` in `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` it's like a shortcut/variable name for the value `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` and could be different.